# Accessing a global variable from an onClickListener inside an alertDialog

Tags: java, android, global-variables, onclicklistener

[image]

In the marked line `str` asking me to set `str` as a local variable

```
public void alertShow(String s){
    //Game Ended...!!!
    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    if(s.equals("You") || (s.contains("P")))
        alertDialog.setTitle("Congratulations...");
    else
        alertDialog.setTitle("Game's Up...");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    if(s.equals("You") || s.contains("P"))
        alertDialog.setMessage(s+" Win The Game...");
    else
        alertDialog.setMessage("You Lose... I Win...");

    final ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    if(s.equals("You") || (s.contains("P")))
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.firecrackers);
    else
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.mmm);

    alertDialog.setView(img);

    // Setting Dialog Cancellation
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button

    //==================Here Problem Starts==========================

    SessionClass sessionClass = new SessionClass();
    final String str = sessionClass.getPlayer();
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i;
            if (str.contains("1"))
                i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, Toss.class);
            else
                i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, Game2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    //=====================================================

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Main Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I want to access str from onClickListener which is declared outside onClickListener.
I have tried the following code but it is not accessing the variable.

Comment: make `str` String `final`

Comment: tried that @ρяσѕρєяK but unfortunately not working. And now I'll be editing the code using final.

Comment: what is not working? what message you get?

Comment: you cannot set `str` as `public`

Comment: In place of 
`SessionClass sessionClass = new SessionClass();`
It would be 
`SessionClass sessionClass = (SessionClass)getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the `str` variable as `final`, and then you can access it from `onClickListener`

Comment: tried that @VivekSingh but unfortunately not working. And now I'll be editing the code using final.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing now. any compile issue or runtime issue?

Comment: what is the scope of your `str` variable?

Comment: the scope would be the function inside which `str` is decleared but, since `onClickListener` is a class, it can't access `str` from there. So I'm looking for an another way by which it can be accessed.

Comment: Is the code presented here by you lies in the same method?

Comment: submit the entire function. please check. the function was working fine when written seperately in two classes. but after merging those two functions together and shifting it to the base class to access the function following inheritance, that snippet is not working properly. the alert dialog is visible and the negative button is also working fine.

Comment: also add a null check on your variable  as `if (null != str && str.contains("1"))`

Comment: while redirecting I've set setPlayer("1P") but it is getting null... don't know how... have to check... but your suggestion is working perfectly... Thanks all of u...

Answer (score 0):

From docs of [annonymous inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

**Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope, and Declaring and Accessing Members of the Anonymous Class**

> Like local classes, anonymous classes can capture variables; they have the same access to local variables of the enclosing scope:
>
> An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
>
> **An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.**

Mark your string as `final`, then you can use it.

Comment: tried that @SURESH but unfortunately not working. And now I'll be editing the code using final.

Comment: In place of 
`SessionClass sessionClass = new SessionClass();`
It would be 
`SessionClass sessionClass = (SessionClass)getApplicationContext();`

Answer (score 0):

Final , should let you access your variable inside your AlertDialoge ,
can you confirm that you actually getting string from this method (getPlayer();)?

the reason I am asking this is (you are not checking for null) and if that method returns null then you will get error when you want to check if null has "1".

Comment: yes, `getPlayer()` method is already used earlier to in the app which is returning a string '1 Player' or '2 Player'.

Comment: Glad you got it working at the end, but disappointed you did not select this as an answer or atleast upvoted this, cause I think I mentioned final will work and you are getting Null from your methode and it appears to be the case, anyway please next time check before you reply to a answer. regards

Comment: very sorry 4 for that. I can't upvote since i'm new here and both of u replied same time. and helped me equally. and I became the dumbest guy by not checking that 4 that specific activity. and there was also a mistake in my code which was the cause for showing null. and that was

In place of 

`SessionClass sessionClass = new SessionClass();`

It would be

`SessionClass sessionClass = (SessionClass)getApplicationContext();`

none rectified that. I rectified that by myself.

That was the real cause. bdw Thanks a lot for helping me. Next time I'll definitely check yours.